# got some static data,not much,how should I store them

Tags: ios, core-data, preload

I got some static data, not too much, maybe 50-60 counts, which is necessary for view's content, so I have to preload them into my app. The data is not plain, not appropriate for property list,and it is too small so I'm not sure if core data is fit. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you considered using a property list (.plist file). You can enter the data directly and parse it into your app when required.

Comment: You can based on your requirement. You can use different data store like .plist file, Core data, NSUserDefaulf,Make a file with xml and json format and store into it. You can use whatever which is feasible to u.

Comment: You say "the data is not plain." What do you mean? Custom classes?

Comment: @Rob Yep,it's two model, one contains an array that consists of the other

Comment: Then I'd be inclined to make them conform to `NSCoding` and use archiver as Wenchen escrowed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can convert them into NSData then save into a file.

For example:

```
//Write
NSArray * array = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4"];
NSData * data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
[data writeToFile:yourpath atomically:YES];
//Read
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:writeToFile:yourpath];
NSArray * array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: Yep. Of course, if the model data consists of custom classes, he'll need to make it conform to `NSCoding`, as outlined in the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE). And also, one can obviously bypass the `NSData` objects, and directly archive and unarchive to and from files.